# Django MongoDB Engine InvalidID

Tags: python, django, mongodb

When using the python shell with the following:

```
>>> User.objects.get(pk=1)
```

I get the following error:

```
InvalidId: AutoField (default primary key) values must be strings 
    representing an ObjectId on MongoDB (got u'1' instead)
```

A possible solution to this problem, which did not work for me, may be found here: http://django-mongodb.org/troubleshooting.html

I'm wondering if anybody else has come across this problem and how were you able to fix it?

Comment: Show your code (User class)...

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't use integer primary keys.